# How can I loop many SQL queries in R?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, loops

I am using R Studio, accessing SQL Server 2012 with RODBC package, and I will be running this sql query:

```
NameJan15 <- sqlQuery(connection_name, paste("SELECT column_1,
                   column_2 FROM DBname.dbo.tablename
                   Where column_cd= 'ZZZ' 
                   and column_date between '20150101' and '20150131'
                   AND org_cd= '##########'
                   ORDER BY column_2, column_1 desc;"
                   ))
```

I'll need to perform this query for each month in 2014 and 2015.  That's 24 queries for that one org_cd value, and there are a total of 3 org_cd's in which I need to run that series of queries, for a total of 72 queries.  I'm trying to find out how to make a loop that can cycle through each month of 2014 and 2015 with this query, and hopefully repeat that for each of the remaining org_cd values as well.

In the stack posts and google results I've searched, it looks as though maybe I'll need to do a "for loop", maybe.  But I don't quite know how to make something that complex with my level of knowledge for R (beginner).
Regardless, I was thinking of:

```
for (daterange in c('20140101 and 20140131', '20140201 and 20140231',...,'20151201 and 20151231')){
NameMMMYY <- sqlQuery(connection_name, paste("SELECT column_1,
                   column_2 FROM DBname.dbo.tablename
                   Where column_cd= 'ZZZ' 
                   and column_date between 'daterange'
                   AND org_cd= '##########'
                   ORDER BY column_2, column_1 desc;"
                   ))}
```

But, I don't know how to include assigning a name (NameMMMYY) to the results of each month's query as part of the loop code. Also, I'd be missing the inside apostrophe's in the date ranges, because SQL wants quotes around each date, not the date range.

I'm pretty sure I am not looking to parallelize or parameterize the queries, though I could certainly be wrong on either count.  Beyond this, it seems other posts deal with different types of SQL and/or different packages.

All in all I'd like to know how I can loop this query 72 times due to the different months/years and org_cds, and how to give a name to each query result so I don't accidentally lump all of them into a single name.  Is this feasible?

Even if I must pick only one, looping for dates or looping for org_cd's, it's better than nothing.  I'd choose the looping for dates if it came to that.

Comment: Why not just run 1 query that returns the data needed for all 72 cases and then do the data splitting afterwards? Running separate queries involves a lot of excess overhead.

Comment: I concur with @Alex. In fact, you do not run any aggregation required for iterative queries. Now if df is a very large bulk load, than repetitive queries may be warranted. Otherwise just slice large df in R. Also, consider using months. SQL Server uses `DatePart()` and `Month()` functions. You will avoid declaring a non-existent Feb 31!

Comment: @Alex I'll run the big query first then try to split it up later like you said.

Comment: @Parfait The format for the dates is (char(8), null).  If I happen to include 20150231 in the search, will it just not return everything in February up to the 28/29th day?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
library(lubridate)
begin <- (ymd("2014-01-01") + days(1))  %m+% months(0:23) + days(-1) 
end <- (ymd("2014-01-31") + days(1))  %m+% months(0:23) + days(-1) 
queries <- paste("SELECT column_1,
                   column_2 FROM DBname.dbo.tablename
                 Where column_cd= 'ZZZ' 
                 and column_date between '", begin, "' and '", end, "
                 AND org_cd= '##########'
                 ORDER BY column_2, column_1 desc;")
res <- lapply(queries, FUN=function(x) sqlQuery(connection_name, x))
```

Comment: Do note, with this solution `res` will result in a list of dataframes.